# Why my postgresql do not find my host

Tags: postgresql, debian, postgresql-9.3

My server is Debian 7 and I use PostgreSQL 9.3.

This is my hosts file：

```
root@localhost:/etc# cat hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomian  localhost
127.0.1.1       virtualserver.com       virtualserver

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

And when I want to startup a new console of **psql**:

```
root@localhost:/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main# service postgresql restart
[ ok ] Restarting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server: main.
root@localhost:/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main# sudo -u postgres psql
sudo: unable to resolve host localhost.localdomain
psql (9.3.0)
Type "help" for help.
```

You can see that the the machine can not find the `localhsot.localdomain`. But I changed the root files, and make it as correct in my `/etc/hosts` files and reboot it already.

Comment: In your `hosts` it says `localdomian`, should be `localdomain`.

Comment: It's related to `/etc/host.conf`,  You should change `order` line to  `order hosts,bind`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typo wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your /etc/hosts has a typo, it should be:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain  localhost
127.0.1.1       virtualserver.com       virtualserver

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

localdomain was spelled localdomIAn.